# What word, like 'alviary' is the name for a list of all words in a language?

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought it was called an 'alviary' or 'alveary' (poss. 'alvary'), but I can't find anything on any search engines for it (they're mostly interpreted as bee-keeping expressions or names).

I'm sure there is a word that sounds similar, that means 'a list of all (or most) words in a language'.  e.g. a dictionary without the definitions.

Totally stumped on this one.

Comment: A **lexicon**, for which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/lexicon) gives the definition "**1.2** *Linguistics* The complete set of meaningful units in a language." Although it isn't similar to what you misremember, the closest I can think of is **vocabulary**.

Comment: Personally I would go with "lexicon" as @WeatherVane suggests.  To me, vocabulary suggests something more variable, like the set of words known to a specific individual for example.

Comment: (1) An [***aviary***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aviary) is "a place for keeping birds confined." (2) An [***apiary***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apiary) is "a place where bees are kept."

Comment: If you want to make Google search for exactly the word you type, enclose it in double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Thanks guys, but I'm sure there is a word like the one I'm suggesting.  I know the suggested ones, I downloaded a list with the filename 'alviary' (or whatever it was) after looking for it with that phrase.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica Not sure how you're trying to help there, but thanks.

Comment: @Astravagrant What Jason is doing is giving the only close common words sounding like what you've suggested because no one has heard of 'alveary' (even though that might appear in some dictionary somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Argh.  I found it.  I really thought I'd tried this spelling, but it seems it's so obscure that the first results weren't registering as word-related.

Alveary:    beehive; area of the ear where wax collects; **word-list**

There's a reference to an old app (defunct) that used it as a basis for crossword puzzlers: https://www.puzzlers.org/word-lists

It seems it might be more common in the programming domain (which is where I first heard it), but historically meant a tabular translation list (e.g. words compared to words in different languages).

Comment: No; an alveary is an archaic word for some subset of the English lexicon at any one time. It has/had other meanings, like the union of sets of the headwords of several chosen dictionaries. OED claims to define about 200 000 English words, but it has been claimed that the English lexis now has over a million.

Comment: Great find. The OED says it is pretty rare: "This word belongs in Frequency Band 1. Band 1 contains extremely rare words unlikely ever to appear in modern text. These may be obscure technical terms or terms restricted to occasional historical use, e.g. abaptiston, abaxile, grithbreach, gurhofite, zarnich, zeagonite."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The usage example I gave is one I found in several sources (possibly all from the same original, I guess), but there were clear examples and even books proving this was a valid example, so I'm going to stick with it.  Also, you marked it as a duplicate, but the description clearly showed that it was not, so I have edited the title to make it more clear that it is not looking for just any word, but a very specific word (as described in the description).  If this is a duplicate, can you please explain why this kind of distinction isn't supported by the site?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Have to point out, that if you read the question you linked this to, it's not even the same thing (if I *wasn't* asking for a specific word, which I was).  It looks like you didn't take the time to read either of these questions.  Are you on some sort of quota?  Kind of rushing things...

Comment: The answer lacks supporting evidence from a recognised authority; the word is either obsolete or belongs in a niche area (to cite OED, belonging to the set of 'obscure technical terms or terms restricted to occasional historical use'). It is hardly a standard English usage, and not likely to be of much use to the vast majority of people coming here to get to grips with how English is actually used.  Though the question has now been edited to rule out the normal term, it still asks for a very rare word using an extremely rare precising definition; still, in my judgement, a poor fit for ELU.

Comment: Only the title was edited.  The description always contained distinctive requirements.  The title now distinguishes it even further, but it's not useful enough to the majority so I'd delete it if I could.  Frankly, I'll be back here in a few years (I went through this before) so this "we don't need minority information" is a bit lame. No one knows how many people don't bother to post.  But anyway, it's clearly not a duplicate, so either delete it or set it back to non-duplicate, because that is plain wrong.